# Running a Query that returns the first instance of each ID sorted alphabetically by another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know this may sound a little confusing, but basically I have a query returning a set of "Cluster Names" and "IDs". I want to have the query only select one row for each ID, based on the "Cluster Name", sorted alphabetically.

For example, we are currently having the query return the following:

```
Cluster Name                                    ID
Construction Technologies          239378769
Construction Technologies          239378942
Construction Technologies          239510698
Law and Public Safety              239510698
Health Science                     239510698
Health Science                     240236166
Health Science                     240236203
Construction Technologies          240236209
Health Science                     240236236
Education and Training             240236303
```

If you notice the ID 239510698 shows up three times, for Construction Technologies, Law and Public Safety, and Health Science. What we want is instead of returning this row three times, it would only return it once, which would be the first one alphabetically, Construction Technologies.

Here is the Query:

```
SELECT c.clustername AS ClusterName, MAX(cc.monsterid) AS CountOfClusters
              FROM tblCareerCluster cc
              INNER JOIN tblClusters c ON c.clusterid = cc.clusterid
              LEFT JOIN tblStudentPersonal sp ON sp.monsterid = cc.monsterid
              INNER JOIN tblStudentSchool ss ON ss.monsterid = cc.monsterid
              INNER JOIN tblSchools s ON s.schoolid = ss.schoolid
              INNER JOIN tblSchoolDistricts sd ON sd.schoolid = s.schoolid
              INNER JOIN tblDistricts d ON d.districtid = sd.districtid
              INNER JOIN tblDistrictUserDistrictGroups rurg ON rurg.schoolid = ss.schoolid
              INNER JOIN tblGroups g ON g.groupid = rurg.groupid
              INNER JOIN tblUserGroups ug ON ug.groupid = g.groupid
              WHERE cc.ranking = (SELECT MAX(cc2.ranking) from tblCareerCluster cc2 INNER JOIN tblCareerCluster cc ON cc.monsterid = cc2.monsterid)  
              AND ss.graduationyear IN (SELECT Items FROM FN_Split('2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020,2021,2022,2023', ',')) AND sp.optin = 'Yes'
              AND g.groupname = 'My Districts' AND ug.userid = 14                       
              GROUP BY c.clustername, cc.ranking,  d.district, cc.monsterid, cc.clusterid, d.IRN, d.districtid
```

Let me know if you would like any additional information, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your sample result you have a column `ID` but in the query you have `CountOfClusters` - this is a bit confusing. Please make sure that the sample and query shows the same things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this one maybe simpler

Using the first query returning `Cluster Name` and `ID`

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/611449/1)

```
 SELECT MIN(Cluster_Name) as ClusterName, ID
 FROM <your query>
 GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 1):

```sql
select MIN(A.ClusterName), A.CountOfClusters
FROM
(
    SELECT c.clustername AS ClusterName, MAX(cc.monsterid) AS CountOfClusters
                  FROM tblCareerCluster cc
                  INNER JOIN tblClusters c ON c.clusterid = cc.clusterid
                  LEFT JOIN tblStudentPersonal sp ON sp.monsterid = cc.monsterid
                  INNER JOIN tblStudentSchool ss ON ss.monsterid = cc.monsterid
                  INNER JOIN tblSchools s ON s.schoolid = ss.schoolid
                  INNER JOIN tblSchoolDistricts sd ON sd.schoolid = s.schoolid
                  INNER JOIN tblDistricts d ON d.districtid = sd.districtid
                  INNER JOIN tblDistrictUserDistrictGroups rurg ON rurg.schoolid = ss.schoolid
                  INNER JOIN tblGroups g ON g.groupid = rurg.groupid
                  INNER JOIN tblUserGroups ug ON ug.groupid = g.groupid
                  WHERE cc.ranking = (SELECT MAX(cc2.ranking) from tblCareerCluster cc2 INNER JOIN tblCareerCluster cc ON cc.monsterid = cc2.monsterid)  
                  AND ss.graduationyear IN (SELECT Items FROM FN_Split('2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020,2021,2022,2023', ',')) AND sp.optin = 'Yes'
                  AND g.groupname = 'My Districts' AND ug.userid = 14                       
                  GROUP BY c.clustername, cc.ranking,  d.district, cc.monsterid, cc.clusterid, d.IRN, d.districtid
) A
GROUP BY A.CountOfClusters
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Row_Number` to pick the first result for each ID, ordered by the ClusterName:

```
With CTE as (select *, Row_Number() over (partition by ID order by ClusterName) as RN from [Long sequence of tables and joins])

Select ClusterName, ID from CTE where RN = 1
```

You can make the CTE into a temp table or subquery instead if you would prefer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `row_number` window function to number rows within each partition of ID and then select the row number = 1. if you can't add the function directly to your query you can use a common table expression and use your original query as a derived table:

```
with cte as (
  select *, rn = row_number() over (partition by id order by clustername) 
  from ( << your_original_query here >> ) t
)

select * from cte
where rn = 1
order by ClusterName
```